# Как установить анимированные обои на PC Windows 10 используя C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

Задался целью сделать программ*, способную установить анимированные обои на PC (используя C#). Ступор в том, что не знаю, как сделать основную "фичу" (Как было реализовано в Wallpaper engine и других...).

Comment: https://github.com/moolicc/Wallop возможно будет полезным

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то помогла статья:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/Draw-Behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows-plus

З.Ы. Вообще это лучше в коммент, но у меня не хватает репутации на русской версии стака, так что звиняйте.